# I I want to do Deploy of the site (I made in Visual Web Developer Express Edition) to IIS

Tags: iis

I'll make a homepage with 2,008 Visual Web Developer Express Edition
I set
WebSite1/AppData
/Default.aspx
/Default.aspx.vb
/web.config

, and anything completed build without an error.

How do I have to deploy IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the website and click "Deploy" and then follow the wizard directions.